Access VBA-compare two fields for similar customer name, then update a field with a customer ID from first table
I have two tables with customer data from two different ERP systems.  I am trying to match the customer names from one system to the next and assign the appropriate customer record internal ID. (old system has long customer names that have been shortened and reordered in the new system.) So I am matching similarities. Most of the customer names have at least a city as part of the name.
I am not sure how to parse those out in my code. I am by no means an expert!  I haven't written actual code for 20 years and I am struggling. :-) I was able to loop through the record sets comparing the two fields but it only works for very close matches.
Examples of data:
Table1.CustomerOld            Table2.CustomerNew          Table2.Internal ID     Result if Y
(1)IME-Phoenix VAMC           IME - Phoenix, AZ VAMC       1360                   1360
(2)Elite Medical Distributors Elite Medical Distributors   1270                   1270

Working with about 280,000 records and 300+ customers. Writing an if then else statement for each customer is time consuming and runs really slow.
The sub below works for matches like (2) above, but does not match (1).
Sub CompareCustomers()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsC As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsSO As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rsSO = db.OpenRecordset("SalesLine_Local")
Set rsC = db.OpenRecordset("NS_Customers")


Compare SalesLine_Local.CustomerRefFullName Field to NS_Customers.Name field. If they are similar then
update SalesLine_Local.Customer field with NS_Customers.InternalID field value.

     rsSO.MoveFirst
     Do Until rsSO.EOF
       rsC.MoveFirst
        Do Until rsC.EOF
          If rsSO![CustomerRefFullName] Like rsC![name] Then
            rsSO.Edit
            rsSO![Customer] = rsC![Internal ID]
            rsSO.Update
          End If
        rsC.MoveNext
       Loop
    rsSO.MoveNext
    Loop
   
rsC.Close
rsSO.Close
Set rsC = Nothing
Set rsSO = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub


I have also tried it this way-the very long and time consuming way-but somewhere the comparisons got messed up and I need to go back and manually match them-I really want to avoid that :-) the actual function has 200+ If statements.
Public Function CheckCustomer()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sql As String

    'Identify the database
    Set db = CurrentDb

    'Open table
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SalesLineTbl_2023", dbOpenTable)
   

    Do
        
    'Only update customers that haven't been updated yet.
        If IsNull(rs!Customer) Then
            sql = "Update SalesLineTbl_2023 Set customer=341 WHERE customerreffullname like 'Reliable     Rehab Solutions*'"
           db.Execute sql
        End If
        If IsNull(rs!Customer) Then
            sql = "Update SalesLineTbl_2023 Set customer=1147 WHERE customerreffullname like 'Match One      Medical*'"
            db.Execute sql
        End If
        If IsNull(rs!Customer) Then
            sql = "Update SalesLineTbl_2023 Set customer=1149 WHERE customerreffullname like 'Indian Valley Healthcare, LLC*'"
            db.Execute sql
        End If
        If IsNull(rs!Customer) Then
            sql = "Update SalesLineTbl_2023 Set customer=1152 WHERE customerreffullname like 'Orthocare Supplies Inc*'"
            db.Execute sql
        End If
   'move to the next record
        rs.MoveNext
        
    Loop Until rs.EOF

    'clean up
    rs.Close

    End Function


There is no easy or simple method for this task. You could "normalise" a bit by, for example, replacing " - " with "-" and remove commas but, as it has to be accurate, manual inspection cannot be avoided.

"fuzzy matching" names has been talked to death in numerous forums. As already noted, there is no easy approach, no "magic wand" code, to replace case-by-case inspection.

The provided sample data is not enough. If you attach more records showing Worst Case scenarios, then there might be a way to write a Screening function to get old and new names as parameters and return a value according to the ratio of matched words to all words and their position. If this value is 100% or there is only one record, then you have a perfect match which do not need manual inspection.

Thank you all for your advice.  I removed the spaces in the New Database Customer name and got about 40% match.  I will manually match the remainder.  I appreciate your help!
